# How can I save JSON data to a file with Knockout?

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm trying to learn some stuff with [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) by following the examples.

I've followed the [loading and saving data tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) and read the docs on [Loading and Saving JSON Data](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).

Using the code in these examples, I can't seem to overwrite the JSON file. I tried setting permissions to 777 to make sure that wasn't the problem.

On "success," it just seems to return the data in the file. I confirmed this by loading the HTML file, manually editing the JSON file, deleting tasks, and clicking save. The result I saw in my console was the data from the manual edit of the JSON file.

I have this hosted on my server right now: [index.html](http://curtisblackwell.com/test/), [test.json](http://curtisblackwell.com/test/test.json).

## For the sake of posterity, here is that code:

### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <h3>Tasks</h3>

  <form data-bind="submit: addTask">
    Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
  </form>

  <ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
      <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li> 
  </ul>

  You have <b data-bind="text: incompleteTasks().length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
  <span data-bind="visible: incompleteTasks().length == 0"> - it's beer time!</span>

  <button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>


  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function Task(data) {
      this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
      this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
    }

    function TaskListViewModel() {
      // Data
      var self = this;
      self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
      self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() && !task._destroy });
      });

      // Operations
      self.addTask = function() {
        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
        self.newTaskText("");
      };
      self.removeTask = function(task) { self.tasks.destroy(task) };
      self.save = function() {
        var data = ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks });
        $.post('test.json', data, function(returnedData) {
          console.info(returnedData);
        });

/*
        $.ajax("test.json", {
          data: ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks }),
          type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(result) { console.info(result) }
        });
*/
      };

      // Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
      $.getJSON("test.json", function(allData) {
      var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Task(item) });
      self.tasks(mappedTasks);
      });  
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### JSON

```
[{"title":"Wire the money to Panama","isDone":true},{"title":"Get hair dye, beard trimmer, dark glasses and \"passport\"","isDone":false},{"title":"Book taxi to airport","isDone":false},{"title":"Arrange for someone to look after the cat","isDone":false}]
```

Comment: Your POST call above seems to be using this header: `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which seems will cause trouble on a server expecting json.  Why is the $.ajax call commented out?

Comment: The sample code used both `$.post` and `$.ajax`. They do the same thing, but I wanted to try `$.post` without deleting that just in case it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is working properly, it's posting the correct JSON to the server (you can see this in the browser's dev tools). But because it's just a JSON file on the server, you're not able to overwrite it by simply posting to it. Instead, you'll need to create a web service endpoint on the server that you can post the data to, and the service will then save the file on the server's file system.

Comment: Does that mean it requires server-side technology of some sort? I'm trying to find a way to not use anything server-side so that I can run a project from Dropbox.

Comment: Yes it needs server side - I think you need to read up on Dropbox, and server side code a bit - what you are trying to do isn't a Knockout or JSON issue unfortunately

Comment: I realize Dropbox can't run server-side code. I was just confused about what was possible with Knockout/JS.